# Postgres Specific table access

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-9.5

We have a requirement in our Postgres Database, We want to give specific table permissions to a particular set of user, we also have airflow in our environment which syncs tables, but sometimes any new columns are added to a table so we have to drop the table, due to which the specific table access for the user is gone. Access to a specific table is given through GRANT. Can you guys suggest us a way in which specific table access can be given, and will remain if the table is dropped and recreated?

Comment: Why are you dropping the table and not using Alter ?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a table is dropped, all grants are gone. There is no way to avoid that.

You should put all your grants into a SQL script, put that into your version control system (e.g. Git) and then run it after you applied all your migration scripts.

Schema migration tools like Liquibase, Flyway or Sqitch help you organize this.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to drop a table to add a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE tab ADD newcol integer NOT NULL;
```

Then, you can use default privileges to automatically grant privileges on all new tables created by user `creator`:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE creator
   GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON TABLES TO anotheruser;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered moving the table to a new schema? Then you could grant user access to the schema and drop and create tables with consistent permissions.